# how to remove last letter from string in react js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to remove last character from a string in react

`val = "string"`

`const newVal = value.split("");`

i tried this but this didn't helped.

Comment: val.slice(0, -1);

Answer (score 1):

Since React is javascript, you can use substring:

```
const newVal = val.substring(0, val.length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you try to "delete" the last character, it means that you want to get the character (0, length - 1).

**(method) String.substring(start: number, end?: number | undefined): string

Returns the substring at the specified location within a String object.**

So it's will working:

```
val = "string";
// const newVal = value.split("");
const newVal = val.substring(0, val.length-1);
```